# Equality between integrals

Tags: integration

Which of the two equality is right?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: At the right hand side, are the limits referring to $x$ or $-x$?

Comment: Hi @velutluna, the limits refering to x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from second one's RHS its same as $-\int _{-a}^{-b} f (-x)dx $ now substituting $-x=u $ we have $-dx=du $ . At $x=-a,-b ,u=a,b $ thus its $\int _a ^b f (u)du=\int _a ^b f (x)dx $

Comment: Hi @Archis Welankar, thus the x on the left side of the second integral isn't equal to the x on the right side of the second integral? "Left x=namesake right x"?

Comment: Yes they are different .